# how can we include installed gem in controller in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed gem successfully.But how can we use use in controller?

Answer (score 1):

Look inside of `config/environment.rb`. Inside of the `Rails::Initializer.run` block you should see a commented-out note that describes using `config.gem`.

You want to add the gem that you need with that method, like this:

> config.gem "foo"

There are other options that you might need, depending on what gem you are trying to use. Mention what it is, and I can be more specific.

Also be sure to read [the docs for the gem method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html#M002064).

Comment: You're welcome. If it answered your question, please click the checkmark and the up-arrow. On this, and any other questions you ask on this site. It's the coin of the realm around here.

Answer (score 0):

Add require 'gem' to top of controller or specific method.

Sample use of rubyzip gem for ex

```
def zip(data, filename)
   require 'zip/zip'
   require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
   zipfile = "/tmp/rubyzip-#{rand 32768}"
   Zip::ZipOutputStream::open(zipfile) do |io|
     io.put_next_entry(filename)
     io.write data
   end
   zippy = File.open(zipfile).read
   File.delete(zipfile)
   zippy
end
```